# Workaround for OpenRasta with Optional QueryString Parameters

Tags: api, rest, query-string, openrasta

I have seen [this bug report](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta/ticket/141) from last year.

I was wondering if there is a work around anyone has implemented or can suggest to allow matching when there are optional query string parameters using openrasta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.1 makes querystrings optional already, have you tried on that version?

Comment: I thought I was but after reviewing it looks like I am using version 2, I will update and let you know. Thank you